# How to create a 1D mesh from a curved line (with ToElementMesh)

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I want to create an element mesh from an arc $x=Rcos(\varphi), y=Rsin(\varphi)$, with $R=100, \varphi \in [0,\pi/4]$ which looks like this:

```
Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 100, {0, Pi/4}]]
```

[image]

I want to discretize the region with 8 elements, so I tried something like this:

```
ToElementMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> Table[{100 Cos[phi], 100 Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, Pi/4, 1/8 Pi/4}],
    "MeshElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}}]}
]
```

This results in:

```
ToElementMesh: The element dimension of LineElement[{{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6},{6,7},{7,8},{8,9}}] is not consistent with other elements that are of dimension 2.
ToElementMesh: A mesh could not be generated.
```

I used this example for 1D from the docs as a template (this is the only example of 1D element meshes from the docs):

```
ToElementMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> Partition[Range[0., 1., 1/9], 1], 
    "MeshElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}}]}
]
```

The problem seems to be that the dimension of the "Coordinates" is {9,2} instead of {9,1}, but I haven't been able to figure out how to deal with this. Can this be done with ToElementMesh or is there another way to do this?

EDIT: This does what I wanted:

```
MeshRegion[
    Table[{100 Cos[phi], 100 Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, Pi/4, 1/8 Pi/4}], 
    Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen `MeshRegion` and `DiscretizeGraphics`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the tip, tried that now and DiscretizeGraphics does the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `ToElementMesh` the result will always be a mesh of the full region. What you want to do in this case is to generate a boundary mesh were the embedding dimension is not the same as the region dimension:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToBoundaryMesh[
 "Coordinates" -> 
  Table[{100 Cos[phi], 100 Sin[phi]}, {phi, 0, Pi/4, 1/8 Pi/4}], 
 "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
      5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}}]}]

(* ElementMesh[{{70.7107, 100.}, {0., 70.7107}}, Automatic] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this works.

Comment: @inot12, you are welcome.